# Mask specific values in column after reading csv file

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I'm having trouble finding the correct way to mask specific values from a column after reading a csv file. I found how to create a masked array after creating an array directly in the code.

If I'm reading a file with
`data = np.genfromtxt("file")`
and I want to mask all the "NA" entries from the column labeled "Age", how would I write that out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could create `np.ma.array` and then use `mean` to get the desired result. The mask in the `np.ma.array` could be set to the result of `arr.isnan()` which would mask all `NAN` values

Here is the link for reference:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.mean.html